# how to start minecraft with vbs?

Tags: vbscript, minecraft

I'm working with a startup on my computer and I'm wondering how to start Minecraft with vbs.

Here is the code I have:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.sleep 200
wshshell.Run "chrome.exe"
WScript.sleep 200
wshshell.Run "start minecraft here"
WScript.sleep 200
WshShell.Run "C:\Users\username\Desktop\"
WScript.sleep 200
WshShell.Run "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Discord.lnk"
WScript.sleep 999
WshShell.Run "TASKKILL /F cmd.exe /T"
```

i only want it so it start Minecraft launcher. The problem for me is can't find it. I have try to start it with a shortcut some I have on the desktop. and if you see any more problems with my code so say that to, I'm new on vbs.

Comment: You should find the path of your program and make it as a shortcut !

Comment: i have it dident work

Comment: Which vbscript did use to create the shortcut and what is the absoulte path of Minecraft ???

Comment: @Hackoo the vbscript dident create any shortcut i used that minecaft install on the desktop and im not sure what the path is, i think it is: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft Launcher\MinecraftLauncher.exe" but its not working when i put that there

Answer (score -2, accepted):

An easy workaround is simply to move the minecraft installation out from the Program Files (x86) folder to something that requires a bit less rights. This worked for me.

Comment: Thank I going to test that! But does it matter where I install it as if I can install it on the desktop?

Comment: And do i need to unistall the whole minecraft or just the launcher?